# RhinoMocks - Not specifying all parameters in AssertWasCalled

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am using RhinoMocks. Now I want to assert that some function was called, but I only care about one of the arguments. Can I do a `AssertWasCalled` where I only specify one argument?

In the following example I'd like the ignore what was sent to the second argument of SomeOtherFunction(). I.e. I want to check that SomeOtherFunction was called with first parameter 123 and I don't care what the second parameter was.

```
[Test]
public void SomeTest()
{
    var myMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISomeInterface>();    
    var myObj = new MyClass(myMock); 
    myObj.foo()

    myMock.AssertWasCalled(factory => factory.SomeOtherFunction(123, null));  
}
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can specify the 2nd argument as `Arg<T>.Is.Anything`, then the actual value gets ignored.

However note that using this you need to use Arg for all arguments. Which means you need to use on the first argument: `Arg<int>.Is.Equal(123)`.

Comment: Where do you use `Arg<T>` exactly? like this? `factory.SomeOtherFunction(Arg<int>.Is.Equal(123), Arg<T>.Is.Anything)`